# senquentially loading pages in divs by time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to load some pages in divs, each one in its time. Let me explain...

I have a table...

```
    <table id="table4">
    <tr>
        <td>Id:</td>
        <td>Nome:</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1515</td>
        <td>Thiago</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2015</td>
        <td>Guttierre</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Each "id" represents a piece of a link. Like this...

> http://test.com/1515

I loaded this page (http://test.com/1515) into a DIV.

The point is... I have to change the first page loaded into the div(http://test.com/1515) for the next page(http://test.com/2015). According to the table.

How can I set a time to change the content of the DIV?

Thanks,

Thiago.

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Guys, I wanna to do this....

Load a page into a DIV...

```
$("#dialog").load('www.test.com/' + 1515 + '.aspx');
```

After 90 seconds the DIV loads the other value...

```
$("#dialog").load('www.test.com/' + 2015 + '.aspx');
```

I can't do this, I dont know why. I did a test with...

```
$("#loadedPage").fadeOut(50000);
```

And it only faded out after the last loaded page. Help me!. Please!

Comment: I think this needs further explanation--maybe show the "before" & "after" code? And not sure what you mean by "Set a time to change".

Comment: If Id and Nome are table headers then you aught to use <th> else you might have issues with styling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who has the same problem. How I fixed it (by my way)...

```
 e.preventDefault();
    //Define as variáveis
    var aux = 2;
    var IdOsArray = new Array(); // 
    var idSOS = $("#table4 tr:nth-child(" + aux + ") td:nth-child(1)").text();
    var i = 0;


    //Verify on table
    while ((idSOS != "") && (idSOS != undefined) && (idSOS != null) && (idSOS != "Número")) {
        IdOsArray[i] = $("#table4 tr:nth-child(" + aux + ") td:nth-child(1)").text();
        idSOS = IdOsArray[i];
        i++; aux++;
    };


    i = 0;
    function _(i) {
        idSOS = IdOsArray[i];
        $("#dialog,#closediv").css({ 'display': 'none' });
        if ((idSOS != "") && (idSOS != undefined) && (idSOS != 'undefined') && (idSOS != null) && (idSOS != "Número")) {
            _show(idSOS);
            setTimeout(function() {

                i++;
                return _(i)
            }, 10000);
        } //end IF

        else { _hide() };

    };

    _(i);

    function _show(idSOS) {

        var maskHeight = "99%";
        var maskWidth = "99%";
        $('#mask').css({ 'width': maskWidth, 'height': maskHeight });

        //efeito de transição
        $('#mask').fadeIn(800);
        $("#dialog").fadeIn(1600);
        $('#mask').fadeTo("slow", 1);
        $('#dialog').fadeTo("slow", 1);
        $("#dialog, #mask,#closediv").css({ 'display': 'block' });

        //armazena a largura e a altura da janela
        var winH = $(window).height();
        var winW = $(window).width();
        //centraliza na tela  a janela popup
        $("#dialog, #mask").css('top', '2px');
        $("#dialog, #mask").css('left', '2px');

        //Modal Content

        $("#dialog").load('http://localhost/superdata/osview/osview.aspx?sos=' + idSOS);



    }

    function _hide() {
        $('#mask,#closediv,.window').hide();
    };

    //close click
    $('#mask,#closediv,.window').click(function GetOut(e) {
        _hide();
    });



});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set something on a timer, you can use JavaScript's `setTimeout` or `setInterval` methods:

```
setTimeout ( expression, timeout );
setInterval ( expression, interval );
```

Where `expression` is a function and `timeout` and `interval` are integers in milliseconds. `setTimeout` runs the timer once and runs the `expression` once whereas setInterval will run the `expression` every time the `interval` passes.

So in your case it would work something like this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    //set the contents of the div
}, 5000); //5 seconds
```